# Load Runner Session ID Changes Indefinitely

Tags: session-variables, session-cookies, load-testing, loadrunner

Good day

I'm trying to perform load testing with LoadRunner 11. Here's an issue:

1. I've got automatically generated script after actions recording
2. Need to catch Session ID. I do it with web_reg_save_param() in the next way:

   ```
   web_reg_save_param("S_ID",
   "LB=Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=",
   "RB=; Path=/app/;",
   LAST);

   web_add_cookie("S_ID; DOMAIN={host}");
   ```
3. I catch ID from the response (Tree View):

   ```
   D2B6F5B05A1366C395F8E86D8212F324
   ```
4. Compare it with Replay Log and see:

   ```
   "S_ID = 75C78912AE78D26BDBDE73EBD9ADB510".
   ```
5. Compare 2 IDs above with the next request ID and see 3rd ID (Tree View):

   ```
   80FE367101229FA34EB6429F4822E595
   ```

Why do I have 3 different IDs?
Let me know if I have to provide extra information.

Answer (score 0):

You should Use(Search=All) below Code. Provided your Right and left boundary is correct:

```
web_reg_save_param("S_ID",
"LB=Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=",
"RB=; Path=/app/;",
"Search=All",
LAST);

web_add_cookie("{S_ID}; DOMAIN={host}");
```

For Details refer HP Mannual for web_reg_save_param function.

Comment: It's almost helped. Now I've got identical IDs for response (Tree View) and Replay Log, but in the next request (Tree View) ID is changed

Comment: Loadrunner handles cookies automatically. Try removing all the web_add_cookie functions and run the script, this helped me most of the times.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see what the conflict or controversy is here.  Yes, items related to state or session will definitely change from user to user, one recording session to the next. They may even change from one request to the next.   You may need to record several times to identify the change and use pattern for when you need to collect and when you need to reuse the collected data from a response in a subsequent request.

Take a listen to this podcast.  It should help

http://www.perfbytes.com/dynamic-data-correlation

Comment: The point is that I can't get, why session ID changes from one request to another during one session, as I am trying to emulate single user and server is waiting from my virtual user one already defined session ID?

Comment: Ask the developer.  Most likely because what you think is session information only is also passing state data which will change with each and every request